# Finding latitude and longitude limits for a sub-region given its decimal Latitude and longitude coordinates

Tags: mapping, gis

In order to extract climate data from Copernicus, there's the Sub-region extraction section that allows one to extract data from a region within specific coordinate limits.

I am wondering how should one find the latitude and longitude limits for a specific sub-region, given the decimal Latitude and longitude coordinates of that sub-region.

Taking the example of Lat:-1.29055, Long:36.8667 as an example, what should one do in order to find its North, South, East, and West limits?

Comment: You have a single point so it has no area. You need to find the bounding box of your subregion

Comment: I think your question is not clear. Note: we are a site for programmers so if there are some metadata or rule in Copernicus to get such boundaries, we doesn't know, and this is not the right place to ask for it.

Comment: you're correct Ian Turton, I came to realize that later. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: stop hating Giacomo Catenazzi 